# How is $\frac{1}{(D-2)^2}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{4} * \frac{1} {(1 - \frac{D}{2})^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to solve a problem and I couldn't understand how equation is derived? Can anyone help me out a bit.

$\frac{1}{(D-2)^2}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{4} * \frac{1} {(1 - \frac{D}{2})^2}$

[image]

Comment: The expressions are *not* equal, perhaps you mean $ \frac 14 \frac{1}{(1-D/2)^2} = \frac{1}{(D-2)^2}$?

Comment: @MartinR But in the text book it was given like this? Let me post a image of the expression given.

Comment: Looking at the picture, Martin R is correct.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry a typo. Yes I mean the later one. (D - 2)^2 . I couldn't understand how it  was derived.

Comment: Is the derivation still unclear to you, or is your question resolved now?

Comment: If you're still puzzled, here's something:
$$
(D-2)^2 = (2-D)^2 = \left(2 \left[1-\frac{D}{2} \right] \right)^2 = 4 \left(1- \frac{D}{2} \right)^2
$$

Comment: @MattiP. I got it. Thank you

Comment: $D$ seems to be equal to $\frac{2}{x}$. Then the last term in the brackets must be $3$

Answer (score 1):

With $y=1-D/2$, this is just $\displaystyle\frac{1}{(-2y)^2}=\frac14\frac{1}{y^2}$, which follows from $(-2)^2=4$.